# Mock UNNotificationResponse & UNNotification (and other iOS platform classes with init() marked as unavailable)

Tags: swift, mocking, tdd

I need to mock `UNNotificationResponse` and `UNNotification` so that I can test my implementation of:

`func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)`

However I can't usefully subclass these classes because `init()` is specifically marked as `unavailable`, resulting in compilation errors like this if I try:

`/Path/to/PushClientTests.swift:38:5: Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable`

What alternate approaches can be taken here? I look into going down the Protocol Oriented Programming route, however since I do not control the API being called, I can't modify it to take the protocols I'd write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't!

Instead, decompose your implementation of

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)
```

and test the methods you call from there, instead.

Happy testing :)

Comment: Never say never. :) It's not true to say that you can't. While decomposing the methods is one way of doing it, in doing so, you'll need to make those methods public when they should probably be private in order to test them. Please see my answer here to see how you can mock UNNotificationResponse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64793130/7958285

Answer (score 11):

To do it you do the following.

Get a real example of the object while debugging and save in file system using your simulator.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

let encodedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: notification)

let  path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/notification.mock"

fileManager.createFile(atPath: path, contents: encodedObject, attributes: nil)
```

Find the object in your Mac and add the file in the same target as the test class.

Now unarchive in your test.

```
let path = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "notification", ofType: "mock")

let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path ?? "")

let notification = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data ?? Data()) as? UNNotification
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used the next extension to create UNNotificationResponse and UNNotification instances while implementing unit tests for push notifications on iOS:

```swift
extension UNNotificationResponse {

    static func testNotificationResponse(with payloadFilename: String) -> UNNotificationResponse {
        let parameters = parametersFromFile(payloadFilename) // 1
        let request = notificationRequest(with: parameters) // 2 
        return UNNotificationResponse(coder: TestNotificationCoder(with: request))! // 3
    }
}
```

1. Loads push notification payload from file
2. Creates UNNotificationRequest instance with specified parameters in userInfo
3. Creates UNNotificationResponse instance using NSCoder subclass

Here are the functions I've used above:

```swift
extension UNNotificationResponse {

    private static func notificationRequest(with parameters: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> UNNotificationRequest {
        let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notificationContent.title = "Test Title"
        notificationContent.body = "Test Body"
        notificationContent.userInfo = parameters

        let dateInfo = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: false)

        let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testIdentifier", content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)
        return notificationRequest
    }
}

fileprivate class TestNotificationCoder: NSCoder {

    private enum FieldKey: String {
        case date, request, sourceIdentifier, intentIdentifiers, notification, actionIdentifier, originIdentifier, targetConnectionEndpoint, targetSceneIdentifier
    }
    private let testIdentifier = "testIdentifier"
    private let request: UNNotificationRequest
    override var allowsKeyedCoding: Bool { true }

    init(with request: UNNotificationRequest) {
        self.request = request
    }

    override func decodeObject(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        let fieldKey = FieldKey(rawValue: key)
        switch fieldKey {
        case .date:
            return Date()
        case .request:
            return request
        case .sourceIdentifier, .actionIdentifier, .originIdentifier:
            return testIdentifier
        case .notification:
            return UNNotification(coder: self)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can initialize `UNNotificationContent` objects. I've chosen to rework my push handling methods to take `UNNotificationContent` objects instead of `UNNotificationResponse`/`UNNotification`.

Comment: this is good, only that you won't be able to look up the actionIdentifier unless you pass in two params

Answer (score 1):

If the `UNNotificationResponse` value doesn't matter, and you just want to execute that method of your app delegate, you can accomplish this by creating a mock by subclassing `NSKeyedArchiver` like this:

```swift
class MockCoder: NSKeyedArchiver {
    override func decodeObject(forKey key: String) -> Any { "" }
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```swift
let notificationMock = try XCTUnwrap(UNNotificationResponse(coder: MockCoder()))

appDelegate.userNotificationCenter(UNUserNotificationCenter.current(), didReceive: notificationMock) { }
```

Your app delegate's `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` method will now have been called, allowing you to assert to your heart's content (assuming no assertions against the notification itself, at least).

Comment: the assumption of 'no assertions against the notification itself' is kinda weird for me. Like that's exactly what I wanna test

Answer (score 1):

You can use `class_createInstance(UNNotification.classForKeyedArchiver() ...)`and cast the value as UNNotification

If you want to manipulate its `content` and `date` members you can subclass `UNNotification` and use this same formula «changing class name and cast to your subclass» to create it, then you override those members- which are open- and return whatever you want